# how to make the following curl request to tradeoff analytics in advanced rest client

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud, advanced-rest-client

How to make the below curl request to IBM Tradeoff analytics using chrome advanced rest client plugin
    curl -X POST -u "{username}":"{password}"
    --header "Content-Type: application/json"
    --data @problem.json
    "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tradeoff-analytics/api/v1/dilemmas?
    find_preferable_options=true&generate_visualization=false"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Using Chrome Advanced Rest Client Plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYo1h.png)

[image]

Enter the Request URL above and then select POST method. In Headers form give Content-Type as application/json and in Authorization Username & Password(You will have to click on pencil icon to give username & password). In Raw payload, enter the contents of problem.json file and Click on SEND.

You will get 200 OK with JSON Content!

Comment: I have to tweak the timeout parameter from 30 seconds to zero.  It worked finally.  Thanks.